# caching user specific queries django

Tags: json, django, caching

I have a table which stores media urls (images/videos) and a front end app that consumes these. I am trying to implement caching to make this all run much faster and more scalable.

The issue is I have a likes table that stores which video/images a specific user has liked. I need to return a boolean along with the image/video url that states if the person likes that media already.

Right now I am just caching the json of the images/videos returned and then grabbing that from the cache and inserting a 'liked' attribute in the json response. This looks something like this:

This runs and checks if there is that particular page of media is in the cache:

```
media_json = cache.get('media'+username+str(page))
if media_json:
    new_json = []
    media_ids = []
    for media in tags_json:
        media_ids.append(media['media_id'])

    user_likes = Like.objects.filter(created_by=user,media__pk__in=media_ids)

    for media in media_json:

        liked = False
        for user_like in user_likes:
            if user_like.media_id == int(media['media_id']):
                liked = True

        media['liked'] = liked
        new_json.append(media)

    return JsonResponse({'response': 1, 'media': new_json})
```

if that page of media isn't in the cache then I query the database and create the json response from scratch.

What can I do to cache that a user liked a certain piece of media? Preferably I'd rather not have to query the database again.

Comment: querying the database might not really be a bad thing it might be much more efficient than serializing/deserializing json and iterating through it. You might infact be far better off converting that to a table so that you can use a simple query to find out if a user liked something or not.

Comment: I've run load tests with this and it is about 2x faster than querying the db for the media again. Seems like I can't do anything about the likes though.

Comment: Were the fields in your database properly indexed? Did you do an 'explain' on your query to see if the indexes were actually being used?